# Android ActionBar - No Resource for attribute showAsAction despite API lvl 14

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-xml

I've been working to integrate an Actionbar into my project and can't find the solution for my problem: I'm working with API Version 14 (set in Android Build Target & Manifest File, also cleaned afterwards) and nevertheless my menu xml file says the following error:
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.freelaxing.yamas'
Does anybody have a clue what's going on here?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_account"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_change_account"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_yamas_account"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_selectyamaschannel"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you even need `yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"`? If I'm not wrong this should be used only with `ActionBarCompat` from appcompat-v7 lib. And you do not need one because of targeting for API 14.

So, just try to remove two lines with `yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"` and XMLNS definition `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` from root tag.

Answer (score 0):

You might be check your project-properties file. (target=android-14)

Comment: it says: target=android-15

Comment: what is second xmlns attr in your xml?